# Best way to watch for contracts created from a given account

Tags: transactions, json-rpc, filters

I want to watch the blockchain for new contracts created from some given account. I’ve got an Ethereum node with RPC enabled.

I think, it should be something like this:

1. Call `eth_newBlockFilter()` and get a filter id.
2. Using this filter id, periodically check `eth_getFilterChanges(filterId)` to obtain new block hashes.
3. For each block hash do `eth_getBlockByHash(blockHash, true)`.
4. Check if any transactions from the previous call are made from the given account. For the matching transactions do `eth_getTransactionReceipt(txHash)`.
5. If `contractAddress`  is not null, it contains a contract address I’m looking for.
6. When I don’t need to watch for new contracts anymore, I call `eth_uninstallFilter(filterId)`.

The question is: could I do it in an easier way, with less RPC requests and computations, or not? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to get to that better solution you're seeking because INFURA doesn't support `eth_newBlockFilter()` no more.

In the end I had to settle with the public Augur node to deploy my contracts.

**TL;DR** I couldn't find a different solution to validate contract deployment.